# Stopping button OnClick event with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to run some javascript before my button's click event happens on the server side, but the javascript code runs, and the server side code runs right after that no matter what. Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    SubmitClick = function() {
        if ($("#<%= fuFile.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
            $("#error").html("File is required");

            return false;
        }
    }
  });
</script>

<asp:FileUpload ID="fuFile" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"
  OnClientClick="SubmitClick()" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />

<span id="error"></span>
```

I thought that setting `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` and returning `false` in the javascript function would work, but it's not. My error message gets displayed for a second before the server side code runs.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A good read as to when you should return false. http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically to cancel a client click you would add this `return false;`

You can update your code to do this and it should work: `OnClientClick="return SubmitClick();"`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using JQuery:

```
$btn.on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You will need to combine this with setting `UseSubmitBehavior` back to true for this to work, otherwise it just posts back regardless.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:
Remove `OnClientClick="SubmitClick()"` and set `UseSubmitBehavior` back to true.

Then change your `$(document).ready()` method to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        if ($("#<%= fuFile.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
            $("#error").html("File is required");

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the cancellation of the submitted behavior using return in OnClientClick event.

try this

```
OnClientClick="return SubmitClick()"
```